# Алгоритм преобразования числа в дату

Tags: дата, числа, преобразование-типов

В json приходят данные, в которых дата представлена в виде числа, например 1583960400000 (содержит значение даты 12.03.2020). По какому алгоритму это число преобразовать в дату 12.03.2020?

Comment: `new Date(158396040000)`

Comment: на [Wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F) расписан алгоритм